# How to properly place multiple TextView over imageView

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have an image that I desire to put textViews on top to my Android Application which is the following:

[image]

In order to place textViews on top of the image the only solution I have is to create a FrameLayout, place ImageView first, TextView after and then put padding into the TextView, this is very archaic and time consuming, and I don't know if it will stretch correctly to all android resolutions. This is the way I'm able to do it:

[image]

Is this the only way to do it? Does it have any issue relating to different phones resolutions? or since its based on dp it will always stretch correctly?

Comment: Why do you want to put TextView on top of such an image? Why dont you design a layout that looks like that imageView?

Comment: The image is just an example, its not the one I'm going to use, I made that just for the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a [ConstraintLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintLayout). If you constrain the `Name:` TextView's top to the top of the ImageView and create a chain of constraints (ending with the Information EditText having its bottom constrained to the bottom of the ImageView), that will keep all your views in the bounds of the ImageView.

A layout like this:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    android:src="@color/grey"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/name_text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Name:"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/image"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/image" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/name_text_entry"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/name_text"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/name_text"
    tools:text="Some random text in here"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/id_text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="ID:"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/name_text_entry"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/name_text_entry"/>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/id_text_entry"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/id_text"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/id_text"
    tools:text="Some random text in here"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/information_text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Information:"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/id_text_entry"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/id_text_entry"/>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/information_text_entry"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:lines="5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/information_text"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/information_text"
    tools:text="Some random text in here"/>
```

will produce something like this (the grey background being your ImageView)

[Here's a link since I can't embed images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MGDQn.png)

Comment: I see what you did, I thought it was just a layout mimicking the image, but you actually done what I told, that is indeed interesting, I'll answer later if its what I expected

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using image view, you can use a linear layout and set its background as that image..Then you can add edit text and text views on it.

Comment: And how should I position the textViews within the linear layout to be placed inside of each space? Thats the question actually, cause padding doesn't seem like a good option

Comment: You can use margins to set each of text views at their place. Setting a margin is not a bad option. But still if you don't want to use margin you can use constraint layout and just set constraints to each view where ever you want.